# Do I have to download kernel?

Tags: system-installation, system

I have Ubuntu 14 .. Do I have to download the kernel for this version ?
And what kernel version is suitable for that? 
What is the need for kernel ? What is the function of the kernel in Ubuntu ?

Comment: No you don't need to download any kernel. It is already included, just like an engine is usually included in a car you may buy. The kernel included is optimized for the Ubuntu you have. Just like your car came with an engine optimized for it. The kernel is as fundamental to Ubuntu as the engine is to a car.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel is the core of your OS. Every OS has its kernel (Windows, Mac,etc.). You cannot have any system running without it.
See here for more info:

[What is kernel?](http://www.what-is-what.com/what_is/kernel.html)

[Webopedia](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/K/kernel.html)

Ubuntu is based on linux kernel. The latest Ubuntu 14.10 was released with Linux kernel 3.16 version.But just like other parts of the system the kernel gets updates from Canonical, too.

An average user doesn't have to bother about kernel. It is already built-in the system and gets updated when you update your system from time to time.